# CDF of joint probability function

Tags: probability

I was practicing for my exams and noticed one question which I do not have a worked out solution for to be very difficult. After spending the night on it I decided to ask it here to hope people can help me out to find out where I go wrong.

In [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9sh9.png) question C:
I have $W=y-x $ and boundaries $0\leq x \leq y$. Now I need to find the CDF there is where it goes wrong, I decide to first integrate over x from 0 to y. (because that is the boundary)
$\int_{0}^{y}6e^{-x-2y}dx$, then I get $6e^{-3y}(-1 + e^y)$
After this I see that the domain for W=y-x is from 0 to infinity as y has no upper limit specified. But to keep it in check I also tried from 0 to w.
$\int_{0}^{w}6e^{-3y}(-1 + e^y)dy$
But this gives me: $1 + e^{-3w}(2 - 3e^w)$
And I need to get $1-e^{-2w}$

I hope one of you can guide me in the correct direction and thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to give us the pdf for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1-e^{-2w}$ is the right answer. $P(y-x \leq w)=\int_0^{\infty} \int_x^{x+w} 6e^{-x }e^{-2y}dydx=6\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x}[\frac {e^{-2x}-e^{-2(x+w)}} 2] dx=1-e^{-2w}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, can you maybe elaborate why you chose to integrate from x to x+w, I see that you first integrated over y and then x but shouldn't it be possible in both ways (first x then y)?

Comment: @Weird You have two inequalities: $0 \leq x \leq y$ and $y-x \leq w$. If you want to integrate w.r.t. $x$ first you will have to take into account two inequalities for $x$: $0 \leq x \leq y$  and $x \geq y-w$. It looks simpler to integrate w.r.t. $y$ first.